# Calculate and add percent columns to multiple columns inside a function

Tags: r, function, tidyverse, multiple-columns, percentage

I have a large survey data-set to summarise, I have calculated row counts across multiple columns grouped by treatment and control conditions.

I need to add columns that calculate the percentage for each group and a 'difference' column
(percentage gp1) - (percentage gp2) but can't work out how to do it. Help would be appreciated.
Below is an example of the data:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(janitor)

df <- data.frame(mhst = factor(c(0,1,1,0)),
                 q1 = factor(c(1, 4, 2, 2)),
                 q2 = factor(c(3, 4, 5, 1)),
                 q3 = factor(c(1, 4, 2, 5)),
                 q4 = factor(c(2, 1, 1, 3)),
                 WT1 = c(0.5, 0.3, 6, 1))


q_set_t1 <- c("q1", "q2", "q3", "q4") #choose cols to calc
wt1 <- c("WT1") # choose weights

make_output <- function(mycol, weight) { ## Make the output table for the chosen column and weight
  output <- df %>% group_by_at(c("mhst", mycol)) %>%
    summarise_at(weight, sum) 
  
  names(output)[2] <- "Q_set" #Set the column names
  names(output)[3] <- "weighted_count"
  
  output <- output %>% pivot_wider(names_from = mhst, values_from = weighted_count) #sets MHST nonMHST side by side
  output <- output %>% janitor::adorn_totals()
  output <- output %>% mutate_all(~as.character(.)) #converts to character for easier manipulation when joining vertically
  
  output <- bind_rows(tibble("var_name"=mycol), #adds a blank row above the output table with the var name
                      output, #adds the output table
                      tibble("var_name"="")) #adds blank row at the bottom of each tibble
  
}

cols_output <- pmap(list(q_set_t1, wt1), ~make_output(..1,..2)) # Generates all the output tables by coercing into a lsit and feeding through the make_output function feeding 

q_set_wt <- tibble() # Join them vertically

for(i in 1:length(cols_output)) {
  q_set_wt <- bind_rows(q_set_wt, cols_output[[i]])
}
```

I have tried adding this code:

```
output <- output %>% mutate(percent = mycol/sum(mycol)*100)
```

below in the row under the `pivot_wider()` function but I get an error:

```
"Caused by error in `sum()`:
! invalid 'type' (character) of argument"
```

For the difference column I have tried adding

```
output <- output %>% mutate("0" - "1") (0 and 1 being the names of the mhst levels)
```

below in the row under the `pivot_wider()` function but I get error:

```
! Problem while computing `..1 = "0" - "1"`.
Caused by error in `"0" - "1"`:
! non-numeric argument to binary operator
```

Answer (score 0):

We may modify the function as

```
library(purrr)
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
make_output <- function(mycol, weight) { 
  df %>% 
    group_by(across(c("mhst", all_of(mycol)))) %>%
    summarise(across(all_of(weight), sum), .groups = "drop")  %>%
    rename(Q_set = 2, weighted_count = 3) %>%
    group_by(Q_set) %>%
    mutate(Perc = weighted_count/sum(weighted_count) * 100) %>% 
    ungroup %>%
    pivot_wider(names_from = mhst, 
          values_from = weighted_count, values_fill = 0) %>%
    mutate(Diff = `0` - `1`)  
}
```

and then apply `pmap`

```
> pmap_dfr(list(q_set_t1, wt1), ~make_output(..1, ..2)) 
# A tibble: 15 × 5
   Q_set  Perc   `0`   `1`  Diff
   <fct> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
 1 1     100     0.5   0     0.5
 2 2      14.3   1     0     1  
 3 2      85.7   0     6    -6  
 4 4     100     0     0.3  -0.3
 5 1     100     1     0     1  
 6 3     100     0.5   0     0.5
 7 4     100     0     0.3  -0.3
 8 5     100     0     6    -6  
 9 1     100     0.5   0     0.5
10 5     100     1     0     1  
11 2     100     0     6    -6  
12 4     100     0     0.3  -0.3
13 2     100     0.5   0     0.5
14 3     100     1     0     1  
15 1     100     0     6.3  -6.3
```

Comment: Thank-you, I am getting an error when I apply it to the dataset

Comment: >`.
ℹ It must be numeric or character.

Comment: I've tried adding %>% as.character(.) to the function but I'm still getting it. I appreciate your time

Comment: @Ellie The `>` is from the console symbol.  You just need to copy only from `pmap..`